# Store iTunes Password in Keychain

Tags: macos, itunes, mac-appstore, password, keychain

Is there any way to get Mac OS X to save iTunes/App Store login info (ie username and password) to the Keychain? It's strange that pretty much all other application and website passwords are stored there, but not for iTunes.

Note: I'm not asking about iPhone/iPad etc.

Comment: Are you talking about iTunes or the Mac App Store? Cause your tags and your question say different things...

Comment: Both, because they both have the annoying feature of not wanting to use the keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this using the 3rd party macro/scripting app called "Keyboard Maestro", from http://www.keyboardmaestro.com

Here's a screen shot of the simple script I use. Currently it only works when the App Store is in the background, and gets automatically activated by clicking a web link in Firefox or something, but you get the idea, this could be modified and improved in various ways.

Needless to say, security is compromised by storing your password in plain-text within Keyboard Maestro script, so be sure it's a unique, random password that you don't use *anywhere* else.

[image: screen capture of Keyboard Maestro script]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not. Its is meant to ask for your password for your own safety, so no one except you can buy Apps.

It will remember your password for 15 minutes, though.

Comment: Well then the whole keychain is dangerous, that's where all my eBay, Amazon, etc. web passwords are stored.

Comment: But you can view those passwords after you submit the admin's password, so they are pretty save...

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used eBay nor Amazon, but it seems quite dangerous to me if they let you buy stuff without prompting your password.

Comment: Cydia? I'm asking about Mac OS X, not iOS. That would explain the misunderstanding.

Comment: Doh! I was answering for OS X, but when I came across with the PasswordPilot thingy, OS X just went out of my mind. I'll edit it. The answer is the same, though.

Comment: That's annoying that Apple allows virtually every other password to be saved in the Keychain but its own, and that there are no add-ons that enable saving iTunes passwords.

Comment: Why not allow downloading free apps without entering a password?